# Is zk rollup unsecure?

Tags: zksnark, zksync

We all know that zk rollup uses zk-snark to prove the state transition is valid.

But, now consider that if a malicious relayer creats a proof using incomplete transactions in a batch (e.g. relayer collects 3 transaction tx1, tx2, tx3 but only use tx1 and tx2 to generate zk proof and new state). For the contract, it checks proof and says: okay, it's valid, I'll take it. However, the proof only implies the existence of tx1 and tx2, and the state transition is also based on this.

In this way, the tx3 actually is not included in the new state.

Is it possible to attack? Maybe there is some zk-snark technique issue in it...